# Dynamics of a football

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, momentum, elasticity

Why can toe kick cause greater change in the ball's momentum than kicking with the whole instep in contact with the ball? Perhaps it has something to do with how the foot's momentum is transferred in the two cases..... What's that?

Comment: Do you mean, a toe kick imparts larger momentum to a ball compared to kicking it with whole instep in contact, *when the relative velocity between the ball and the foot are equal*?

Comment: Perhaps, yes....