# How do you determine energy transferred to a trampoline when a ball is dropped on it?

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy, collision, elasticity, vibrations

Suppose a ball of mass $m$ is dropped over a trampoline(consider the young's modulus of the material to be $Y$) from some height $h$. The ball impacts the trampoline, gets slowed down due to the restoring force generated in the trampoline as it curves down, and finally comes to a stop to again begin accelerating in the opposite direction and leave the system after rebounding. What happens in this process is that the ball's energy(K.E) does not remain same as before. We can expect a bit of vibrational energy being transferred to the trampoline in this process. Is there any way to calculate(theoretically)  how much vibrational energy is being transferred to the trampoline. Consider other energy losses as negligible.

Comment: The question would benefit from you showing how you'd approach this problem, or what you have tried.

Comment: This question is one of the _classic_ problems in mechanics, not sure why it's being received so negatively.

Comment: Problem can be assume like spring assuming no energy goes in vibration because if we go on that there are several process as well which need to be accounted like elasticity of trampoline.

Comment: What inputs do you have? Do you know the height the ball gets to after it bounces on the trampoline? If so, you could take the energy of the ball right before it hits the trampoline (`mgh`) and subtract the energy it has right after (`1/2 mv^2`).

Comment: No no... I want a pure theoretical calculation... no experiment

Answer (score 1):

Being physicists, we're going to start with a 1 dimensional trampoline, which is a mass $M$, on a spring with constant $k$, all damped ($c$), so that:

$$ Ma = F $$
$$ M\ddot x = (- c\dot x - k x) + F(t) $$

where $x=0$ is the equilibrium position, and $F(t)$ is an external driving force.

That can be rewritten as:

$$ \ddot x(t)  + 2 \xi \omega_0 \dot x(t) + \omega_0^2 x(t) = F(t)/M $$

where $\omega_0 = \sqrt{k/M}$ is the undamped angular frequency and $\xi = \frac c 2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{Mk}}$ the damping ratio.

Note that this is one of the most used equations in physics and engineering, so I'm not going to solve it here.

The question is now, how do you model the bounce?

I'd go with "a $\pi$'s worth of $\sin(\omega_m t)$", or:

$$ F(t) = A\sin(\omega_m t)\ \ \ \ \ 0 \le \omega_m t \le \pi\ldots $$

$0$ otherwise.

With

$$\omega_m = \sqrt{\frac k {m+M}}$$

and

$$ \frac 1 2 kA^2 = mgh $$

From here, you will get a frequency response function of the "trampoline" and then drive that with the frequency spectrum represented by $\tilde F(\omega)$, the Fourier transform of $F(t)$.

Comment: Being physicicts.... Sure we are

Comment: Seems quite complicated for a high school student... By the way, thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't you just consider the variation between potential energy of the bouncing body before and after the jump at maximum height reached? If we consider that the majority of the energy loss by the body is absorbed by the trampoline and work from e.g. air friction is negligible it should work.

Comment: No no... we want to to calculate it purely theoretically... that's why...

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this question??? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573578/266637  Feels like the ball compresses more during toe kick and so more energy is transferred to it(as potential) which can be used to gain kinetic energy.... Someone please see... if you can help

Comment: It's not quite High School level. You're looking at the "transient" solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator

Comment: Ok thank you...